# Sticky not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have three divs where the first div google charts are being added with an href

the second div is just an overlay followed by a third div which loads iframe

The css has the the third div position absolute and works fine but does not remain on screen when scrolling. if a set the third div position to sticky it sits at the bottom of the screen grayed out under the second div overlay

```js
var btn1_Div = document.getElementById(itemId.itemID + "_div");

//Create and append button
var btn1 = document.createElement("a");
var t = document.createTextNode("Bid Offer Data");
var classId = itemId.itemID
btn1.appendChild(t);
btn1.id = 'boddata';
btn1.setAttribute('class', classId);
btn1.href = "BOD3.php";

btn1_Div.appendChild(btn1);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).attr('id') == "boddata") {
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      var bumid = $(this).attr('class');
      $("#overlay_div").append('<iframe id="bod" width="100%"  height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="true" src="' + url + '?bmu=' + bumid + '"></iframe>');
      $("#overlay").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#overlay_div").fadeIn("slow");
    };
  })
  $("#close_button").click(function() {
    $("#bod").remove();
    $("#overlay").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#overlay_div").fadeOut("fast");

  })
});
```

```css
#overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
}

#overlay_div {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 80%;
  right: 20%;
  bottom: 80%;
  left: 20%;
  z-index: 1500;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px #000;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #000;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #000;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="charts"></div>

<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="overlay_div">
  <div id="close_button">x</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check your console `"ReferenceError: itemId is not defined"`

Comment: You have not defined ItemID.

Comment: And use div ID's whil explaning instead of saying third div second div etc. I having difficulties with understanding.

Comment: It is passed through in the code prior as it is looping though a list and creating dynamic divs for the charts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IS it this you are trying to achive as i understand???

**[DEMO](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=0cb6bfb4d1663c4cbb3d0822214989a8)**

**Edit:** I used fixed as position and and left,right,top,bottom are 0 also added margin as auto. This let me to take the div into the middle of the screen. if you use absolute it goes away while scrolling but fixed is fixing itself there even if you scroll.